# I am not able to get the difference between inFilter and TermFilter, can anyone please guide me on this?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Now as per [termFilter](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch/0.7.0/org/elasticsearch/index/query/xcontent/FilterBuilders.html) and [inFilter](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch/0.14.4/org/elasticsearch/index/query/xcontent/FilterBuilders.html) definitions, both are doing the same job, what is the difference ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the very old Elasticsearch version(As in latest version `inFilter` isn't present, and your link is pointing to Elasticsearch version below 1),  But as mentioned in the documentation link you provided, `termsFilter` is useful to filter one value, while `inFilter` will work even if you pass many terms, and if it matches any one of them.

For ex: you have a `name` field, where three documents have `foo`, `bar` or `baz`, using `termsfilter` you can filter by only one value ie `foo`, `bar`, you will get only one document ,but if you use `inFilter` you can pass all the possible values, and get all the matching documents.

Consider them equivalent to sql statement.

```
name=foo (example of terms filter)
```

```
name in ('foo', 'bar', 'baz') // example of in Filter
```

Comment: That is not the case, termFilter will search for one term in given field, while termsFilter can search for a list of terms in given field.

Comment: @AbhinavBatta what Elasticsearch version you are using? can you point to a latest documentation.

Comment: 7.11.0 thanks !!

Comment: @AbhinavBatta, can you point to this version documentation??

Comment: https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch/7.11.0/index.html

Comment: @AbhinavBatta I don't see the documentation of `Infilter` in 7.11 version link you provided.

Comment: Can be error on my side.